# Keeping a medical patch dry during a shower

Tags: health

I have a pain patch on my back.  I’d like to take a bath.  How can I keep the patch dry?

Comment: Welcome! Did you see [this Q/A](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/11583/showering-while-avoiding-patch-to-get-wet)?

Comment: You're asking about a bath in your text but a shower in the title. These are different propositions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the plastic bag with scotch tape ,take plastic bag cut it in a form of straight then put it on your medical patch with scotch tape around all sides.then you can easily  take shower and kept dry your medical patch.

Comment: he's asking about a bath in his text but a shower in his title. These are different propositions.

Comment: @bigbadmouse to be honest, many people consider those two words to be the same. E.g. I take shower inside a bathtub, so "taking a bath" can easily mean just that. Anyway, even if OP means taking a bath, they can easily just take a shower instead if it will help.

Comment: no, prolonged immersion in water is a different problem than fending off a small stream of water for a shorter period. Does a surfboard make a good boat ?